# How to remove certain part of the object name for hundreds of objects?

Tags: python, scripting, objects

I am new to scripting and trying to find a way to remove the `marketing_` prefix from a few hundred objects in one go. I can get the script below to work fine one the active objects but I cant figure out how to apply it to all objects in the scene or all selected objects.

```
import bpy
bpy.context.object.name = bpy.context.object.name.replace("marketing_", "")
```

How to do that for multiple objects? Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

For selected objects:

```
import bpy 

for o in bpy.context.selected_objects:
    o.name = o.name.replace("marketing_", "")
```

Or for all objects in the scene:

```
for o in bpy.context.scene.objects:
    o.name = o.name.replace("marketing_", "")
```

Or for all objects in the file:

```
for o in bpy.data.objects:
    ...
```

Comment: Link to the docs: https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/stdtypes.html#str.replace

Comment: All objects in scene use  either `[o for o in scene.objects]` or `[o for o in scene.collection.all_objects]`

Comment: That works a treat Martin, thank you so much!